# Eclipse errors after installing ADT Tools

Tags: eclipse, abap-adt

I installed  according to the instructions of the SAP help. Unfortunately, after that, Though I can open eclipse, I cannot open any Project and get the following error messages.

"ABAP communication layer is not configured properly. This might be caused by missing Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 (x64) Runtime DLLs. Consult the installation guide or download page for further details on how to install this component.
JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\sebastian.wilhelm\eclipse\java-2023-12\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\888\0.cp\lib\sapjco3.dll: Can't find dependent libraries"

"An internal error occurred during: "Create system projects".
com/sap/adt/compatibility/discovery/IAdtAtomCategory"

"Unhandled event loop exception. An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.sap.conn.jco.eclipse (886)"

I also reverted the installation but it didn't help.

I don't know what to do. Any help is highly preciated as I cannot work currently.

Thanks, Sebastian

I also reverted the installation but it didn't help.

Comment: That doesn't sound good. Have you manually deleted or changed files in the installation directory? It might also caused by an anti virus software that falsely removed `sapjco3.dll`. Does a fresh installation of Eclipse and the ADT Tools plugin work?

Comment: No. I have just installed the plugin from the SAP Site. Nothing else. I haven't installed eclipse fresh. I have a lot of templates which I don't want to lose.

Comment: Do the following: First try a fresh installation with a fresh workspace. If this works, in the fresh installation open your old workspace which should bring back all your templates (just in case, make a backup of the workspace before).

Comment: I reinstalled eclipse. When opening eclipse I get the following error
ABAP communication layer is not configured properly. This might be caused by missing Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 (x64) Runtime DLLs.

Comment: I reinstalled the VB DLLs. It is now working! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reinstallation of eclipse and adt worked!